# Is applying asyncio library to written library before possible?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

https://github.com/jborean93/smbprotocol

We use the library above in our project, but we want to accelerate the API by either using thread pools or asynchronous programming which is provided by asyncio library. We wonder if we can use this library with the operations in which I/O bound operations take place. If it can be achieved, could you give some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
The idea is to run all legacy blocking IO calls in executors - the asyncio library provides the [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) call, which takes care of that.

Just, since it is I/O bound, provide a custom executor instead of the default one created by asyncio (when you pass "None" as the executor): the default is conservative, as the task to be executed might be CPU bound - so it have a number of workers proportional to the available CPU cores. For an I/O bound task, you might get good results around 15 workers for an average network link, and much more if you have bandwidth of the order of 1GBpS.

The usage could not be simpler: just write *your* app with co-routine functions made to be run under the asyncio loop, and call the legacy lib with
`asyncio.create_task(asyncio.run_in_executor(executor, legacy_function, *args_to_legacy_function))`

Comment: Can I simply convert the code blocks, which contain legacy synchronous file I/O bound operations, into asynchronous containers and let the event loop locate the lines expected to have I/O bound operations on its own? Or given the lines expected to have I/O bound operations, do I need to create asynchronous containers, put appropriate awaits in place by myself?

Comment: The event loop won't guess anything. If it is a synchronous operation, you have to wrap it in an asynchronous call - which can be a normal function, to be called with `run_in_executor`, or replacing the sync lib by an async lib with calls that can be awaited (for example, replacing the "requests" lib with "httpx" : https://github.com/encode/httpx ) .

For fast file tasks, like reading a couple hundred text lines, you might just keep the sync. code, if you are gaining 10-100 times the wait by making the networking async.